# Rotman's Homological Algebra, Theorem 7.8, showing two definitions of Ext have the same values

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

I have a question regarding one detail in his proof of this theorem below.
Note: in the proof, he uses $\operatorname{Ext}^n(C,..)$ to denote $R^n\operatorname{Hom}(C,..)$ and $\operatorname{ext}^n(...,A)$ to denote $R^n \operatorname{Hom}(...,A)$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I understand everything except for the highlighted isomorphism near the end of his proof.  How did he conclude that $\text{Ext}^1(K_{n-2}, L^0) \cong \text{ext}^1(K_{n-1}, A) $?

At first, I thought it was because we prove $\text{Ext}^1 \cong \text{ext}^1$  and we also have this isomorphism $\text{Ext}^1(K_j, L^i) \cong \text{Ext}^1(K_{j-1}, L^{i+1})$ for $i,j \geq 0$, so that would imply
$$  \text{ext}^1(K_j, L^i) \cong \text{Ext}^1(K_j, L^i) \cong \text{Ext}^1(K_{j-1}, L^{i+1}) .$$  But that would means we would have
$$\text{Ext}^1(K_{n-2}, L^0) \cong \text{ext}^1(K_{n-1}, L^{-1}).  $$
But he never defined what $L^{-1}$ is and if we defined $L^{-1} = A$, then he would have to show that this isomorphism $\text{Ext}^1(K_j, L^i) \cong \text{Ext}^1(K_{j-1}, L^{i+1})$ is true for $i,j$ not necessarily greater than or equal to 0 as well.

Thank you very much.

Edit: Corollary 6.16 is below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}\DeclareMathOperator\ext{ext}$The string of isomorphisms at the end of the proof has a typo in the first step that carries through and makes for the senseless step that you have highlighted (the highlighted step is senseless because it is saying $\ext^1(K_{n-2},A)\cong \ext^1(K_{n-1},A)$, once we recall $\Ext^1\cong \ext^1$ and $L^0=A$). Here's what the first isomorphism should be:
$$\Ext^{n+1}(C,A) = \Ext^{n+1}(C,L^0) \cong \Ext^1(C,L^n)$$
with that correction in place, we get the desired isomorphism of $\Ext^{n+1}$ and $\ext^{n+1}$ (assuming I haven't introduced any new typos :)):
\begin{align*}
&\Ext^{n+1}(C,A)\cong\Ext^1(C,L^n)\cong \Ext^1(K_{n-1},L^0)\cong\ext^1(K_{n-1},L^0) \\
&= \ext^1(K_{n-1},A) \cong \ext^{n+1}(C,A)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see, I just want to verify, so the corollary 6.16 he mentions in his proof states that, let $0 \to A \xrightarrow{\epsilon} E^0 \xrightarrow{d^0} E^1 \xrightarrow{d^1} ....$ be an injective resolution and let $L^0 = \text{im} \epsilon$ and $ L^n = \text{im} d^{n-1} $ for $n \geq 1$, then $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A) \cong \text{Ext}^{n}(C,L^0) \cong ... \cong \text{Ext}^{1}(C,L^{n-1})$.  So since his index is off like you said, is that why $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A)  \cong \text{Ext}^1(C, L^n)$ instead of isomorphic to $\text{Ext}^1(C, L^{n-1})$?

Comment: @Khoata Yeah, $A\cong \operatorname{im}\varepsilon = L^0$, so it should start with $\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A)\cong\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}(C,L^0)$. The rest of the dimension-shifts are fine. (The term for this phenomenon is indeed "dimension-shifting")

Comment: I see, so we kinda have $\text{Ext}^{n}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A) \cong \text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,L^0)$? Then because from Corollary 6.16, we have $\text{Ext}^{n}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{1}(C,L^{n-1})$, this implies $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{1}(C,L^{n})$??

Comment: @Khoata There is no $\operatorname{Ext}^n(C,L^0)\cong \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A)$. If you can get your hands on Rotman 2000, he gets the indexing right, but it's only written out in the case of Tor: See Cor. 6.23 and Thm. 6.32.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I edited the question to include Corollary 6.16 that he mentions in the proof.  Also, when I said $L^0$ in my comment, I meant $L^0 = \text{im}(\epsilon) $ as in the corollary.  So what I was thinking is that we have $\text{Ext}^{n}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{1}(C,L^{n-1})$ so this implies $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{1}(C,L^{n})$ and since we have $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A) $, this would imply that $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,A) \cong \text{Ext}^{n+1}(C,L^0) \cong \text{Ext}^{1}(C,L^{n})$.

Comment: Yes, that seems to clarify everything.